# Getting errors while developing plugins

Tags: plugin-development

So I've wasted a day because I couldn't figure out how to get an error back from an action I'm using in a plugin...

```
$newUserSuccess = craft()->users->saveUser($newUser);
```

`$newUserSuccess` was empty, and it turns out the reason was because the new user was trying to register with an existing user's email address, which fails. I could not figure out how to get any useful information back. I had tried this:

```
if (!$newUserSuccess)
{
    AutoUserEntryPlugin::log('Couldn't save the new user: '.print_r($newUser->getErrors(), true), LogLevel::Info);
    throw new Exception(Craft::t('Couldnt save the user.'));
}
```

but in the log all that was output was "Couldn’t save the new user: Array"

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting `"Couldn’t save the new user: Array"` because `$newUser->getErrors()` returns an array of validation errors (in case there are more than one).

If you want to print them all to a log file, you can do something like this:

```
AutoUserEntryPlugin::log('Couldn't save the new user: '.implode(', ', $newUser->getErrors()), LogLevel::Info);
```

Comment: If I use

    AutoUserEntryPlugin::log('Couldn’t save the new user: '.implode(', ', $newUser->getErrors()), LogLevel::Info);

I get an error on that line;

PHP notice
Array to string conversion

[edit: how do you get line breaks in these comments?!]